# issue refreshing div with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some code that upon clicking on a button, a div is populated as seen in the code below. The problem is that I want to ensure that if the button is clicked multiple times, that the div reloads so to speak. I tried implementing this with the refreshDiv function below, but with this included the action of clicking the button does nothing.

```
 function buttonClickHandler() {

    var divString = "foodJournal";
    refreshDiv(divString);

    var divID = document.getElementById("foodJournal");
    var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
    legend.innerHTML = "Food Log";
    legend.setAttribute('id', "legend");
    divID.appendChild(fieldset);
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);

     //refreshes food journal div
     var refreshDiv = function(element) {
         node = document.getElementById(element);
         while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
             node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
         }
     };
 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code? Does it reach the `refreshDiv()` method?

Comment: Could you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your html and js included.

Comment: If it is possible for your project, I also suggest a javascript library like jQuery. All this could be replaced by a few lines.

Comment: Don’t listen to these guys. jQuery is icky. :) Also, you can just do `.id = "legend";`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to `refreshDiv` before actually declaring the variable. Move the variable declaration above the call to it and it should work.

```
function buttonClickHandler() {

    var divString = "foodJournal";
    //refreshes food journal div
    var refreshDiv = function(element) {
        node = document.getElementById(element);
        while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
        }
    };

    refreshDiv(divString);

    var divID = document.getElementById("foodJournal");
    var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
    legend.innerHTML = "Food Log";
    legend.setAttribute('id', "legend");
    divID.appendChild(fieldset);
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code, as you have it written will result in an error in the console.  On Chrome, you would see:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

pointing right at the first `refreshDiv(divString)` statement.

While variables are hoisted in javascript, only the declaration is hoisted, not the assignment.  ([see fiddle with error](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu975/))

A simple fix would be to move both the variable declaration and its assignment above the first call to `refreshDiv`. ([Simple fix example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu975/1/))

```
function buttonClickHandler() {
    var divString = "foodJournal";

     //refreshes food journal div
     var refreshDiv = function(element) {
         node = document.getElementById(element);
         while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
             node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
         }
     };

    refreshDiv(divString);

    var divID = document.getElementById("foodJournal");
    var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
    legend.innerHTML = "Food Log";
    legend.setAttribute('id', "legend");
    divID.appendChild(fieldset);
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);

 }
```

As written in your sample, there really is no reason to have a separate method to clear the div.  If this wasn't just to illustrate the problem you were having, you might consider refactoring the code a bit to reduce some of the redundancy and remove the unnecessary function call.